# How to get text from within div tags

Tags: python, html, xpath, webdriver

I've tried variations of the code below but cant seem to grab the SKU numbers. The length of the all_elements list is 60 which is perfect (because this is 1/60 on the page), but when I try and print it out it's blank.

```
all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="item-list__meta"]')

numele = len(all_elements)

for i in range(numele):
    print(all_elements[i].text)
```

```
<div class="item-list__more-content">
<div class="item-list__meta">
SKU: 55404407<br>
Stores with stock: 76%<br>
Stores with discount: 100% </div>
<div class="item-list__actions">
```

Comment: I'm no Python expert, but I think the `text` property of an element in ElementTree returns the first text node; the documentation advises using `"".join(element.itertext())` to get all the text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the SKU line you can try with that locator:

```
//div[@class="item-list__meta"]/br[1]/preceding-sibling::text()
```